# What does Uber actually do with passenger ratings?

Tags: taxis, uber

We all know and love the ratings system that Uber uses.  The driver gets to rate you and you get to rate the driver.   But... what does Uber actually do with that information?

For example, as a passenger I am not aware that I get to choose the car based on the average rating of the driver. So, what difference does this rating make?

Comment: I use Uber a lot, I have noticed that no driver had a rating less than 4, this could mean that this is the minimum acceptable rating for drivers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an Uber driver rating drops below a certain level, the driver is warned and eventually may be deactivated.

Drivers see the ratings of passengers and may choose not to accept a ride if the passenger has a low rating.

Comment: Thank you.  Presumably there are rules governing when they can not accept a ride. Do you know what those are?

Comment: There are no rules about a driver accepting a ride from a passenger. Even if a passenger has a rating of 1.1, the driver can still choose to pick up. However, it's likely that the rider will abandon a low rating by getting a new account. That is not possible, or at least very difficult, for a driver to do.

Comment: That's interesting that a driver can choose never to accept any rides.

Comment: @eleanora Why is that interesting?  Nobody is forced to be an Uber driver.

Comment: @gerrit Uber may not want customers to see lots of cars on the phone map but not be able to get a ride. That could be bad for its reputation.

Comment: @gerrit, in many places, taxi drivers are required by law to pick up any fare within their service area.